# Would I have performance issues if I use instead of 9 patch, images loaded using Glide?

Tags: android, android-glide, android-imagebutton

I have 3 ImageButtons and about 80 images 9 patched saved in the raw folder. I am using randomly the images using srcCompat property and scaleType with value of fitCenter, in my ImageButtons. Offcourse the size of APK has grown.

If I use Glide to load the images from server

a) would I have problems with scale of the images

b) Can I use something like

```
Glide.with(context)
.load(ArrayWithURL[randomId])
.into(IMAGEBUTTON);
```

Sorry if it is stupid question

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of the Images? Are kind of icons or you are using them for screen saver kind of thing? Basically, you must use Glide but depending on purpose, raw might also work

Comment: Are icons , the quality is not that important

Comment: In that case, proceed with Glide, but keep caching the images.